# Django AttributeError 'tuple' object has no attribute 'regex'

Tags: regex, django, python-2.7, django-urls, django-1.8

I'm using **django 1.8** and having trouble with it. I am trying to import tinymce in my project. When I render it caught

> *AttributeError: tuple' object has no attribute 'regex'*

When I remove the url in url.py it is working. Here is my codes.

**url.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'hizlinot.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),

]
```

**settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for hizlinot project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'b-4jipu5t(+)g(2-7g#s=1rs19dhpj-1-!x1b-*v7s85f-m%&q'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'edebiyat',
    'tinymce',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'hizlinot.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'hizlinot.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You forgot the '`url`'

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
```

> urlpatterns should be a list of url() instances

`url` returns `RegexURLPattern` but instead a tuple is found in your list.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/conf/urls/#url

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @DTing

I tried to add 'url' start of the tinymce url but this time it doesn't appear HTMLField. It's  appears  textarea not HTMLField.

models.py is fine

from tinymce.models import HTMLField

someHtmlEditor = HTMLField(null=True, verbose_name='Karakterlerin İncelemesi')

Comment: That is out of the scope of the original question. It is difficult to tell what the problem is from talking in comments. Try posting another question with the related code and error.

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you so much @DTing. I changed tinymce settings.py before and I forgot. When I fix Tinymce setting.py then I apply your advice It worked! :) Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I know it's not absolutely related to the question, but sometimes this error can be a little deeper than directly in a *urls.py* file.

I got this error and the cause of the problem wasn't in the error stack trace.

I had this problem while browsing the Admin with a custom Admin Class, and the problem was with the method *get_urls()* of this class, which was returning something like:

```
def get_urls(self):
    from django.conf.urls import patterns
    return ['',
            (r'^(\d+)/password/$',
             self.admin_site.admin_view(self.user_change_password))] + super(CompanyUserAdmin, self).get_urls()
```

To fix it:

```
def get_urls(self):
    from django.conf.urls import patterns
    return [
            url(r'^(\d+)/password/$',
             self.admin_site.admin_view(self.user_change_password))] + \
           super(CompanyUserAdmin, self).get_urls()
```

Don't forget the import of 'url':

```
from django.conf.urls import url
```